# .gitignore shows up when I run git status

Tags: git

When I run `git status`, .gitignore is listed under untracked files. How do I prevent it from being listed?

Contents of .gitignore:

```
images/builder/
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can add `.gitignore` to your `.gitignore` file, but you probably just want to commit it anyway considering all of your team members (if there are any others) are probably going to have the same files listed in `.gitignore`.

Comment: Agreed, you should be adding the .gitignore file so everyone shares it.

Comment: Let's be clear: you *could* add it to .gitignore, but you shouldn't. You *should* commit it. (Not just "probably".)

Comment: @Jefromi - Why should commit it? If should, then every git repo will come with a .gitignore checked in.

Comment: @manojlds: *Exactly.* You want *everyone* to ignore certain things like build products (objects, libraries, executables, makefiles generated by automake...), run logs, and whatever else is appropriate for your project. If you have things that only you need to ignore, put them in `.git/info/exclude`.

Comment: @jefromi is mostly(almost entirely) correct, but automake generated makefiles should not be ignored.  You can (and should) ignore Makefile.in, but your project should be designed to work with a vpath build so that makefiles are never generated in the working directory.  Having git status inform you of their existence can catch it when you inadvertantly configure the work dir.

Comment: @WilliamPursell: Hm, I wasn't aware of that. I've definitely seen several projects that ignore their automake makefiles. It seems like as soon as you check them in, you'd start running into problems with them being different on different systems, or with different version of the autoconf pipeline.

Comment: @Jefromi Makefiles definitely should not be checked in, but I'm arguing that they should never appear in the work directory at all and thus don't need to be ignored.

Comment: @WilliamPursell: Oh, my bad, reading fail. Thanks. In any case, we all agree about ignoring toolchain-generated files (in their expected places).

Answer (score 8):

To clarify a bit on what others have said, there are rougly three categories of stuff that are excluded, and git uses different exclude files for each category:

1. Stuff that everybody working on the project wants to exclude — e.g. `*.o`, the names of the generated executables, other build-generated files that you don't want to check in.

   For this case, you use `.gitignore` in the project directories (as you're doing).  Since you want everybody working on the project to share these excludes, you should add the these `.gitignore` files using `git add` and commit them like source files.
2. Stuff that you personally want to exclude for all your projects, but others working on the same projects may not.  For instance, I use the Emacs editor, which creates backup files like `Foo.~1~`, so that's something I exclude personally for all my git checkouts

   For this case, you use a "personal" ignore file, conventionally in your home directory called something like `~/.gitignore`; the name of this file is actually set as a global git parameter, so for instance, you might do:

   ```
   git config --global core.excludesfile ~/.gitignore
   ```

   [As that's a global setting, you only need to do it once.]

   So for my Emacs backup files, I add a pattern like `*~` to `~/.gitignore`.
3. Stuff that you want excluded "locally" in a specific working-tree, but maybe not for other working-trees.

   For this case, you should add exclude entries to the `.git/info/exclude` file.  Since this file is underneath the magic `.git` directory, the status command will never show it as an untracked file (and you can't add it).

Git uses all these exclude files together to decide what's excluded.

Answer (score 2):

Just commit the file.
It will then go away from the list.
(I found this confusing initially.)
You'll still be able to edit it to add more items in the future.
And then commit again to ignore them

Answer (score 2):

`.gitignore` should be a part of your code. You sure don't want to exclude since it's the way to tell your teammates (or yourself in another pc) which files shouldn't be commited